# Checking if the user is already registered

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to create a register for using mysql table as if username and pass is already added it output a msgbox saying you are already registered but what happen is that it always add it even if it already exists ..

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        cn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=sa;Pwd=fadyjoseph21"
        cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test2(Username,Password) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
    cmd2.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, password FROM test2 WHERE username = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
    cn.Open()
    MsgBox("Registered")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("You're already registered")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Do Not Concat strings to make SQL.  Use SQL Parameters.  Your code will crash on all sorts of Irish and French names (eg: `Mike O'Toole`, `Joan D'Arc`) and is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Do Not store passwords as plaintext; hash and salt them.  Is that all you require of a new user is a name and PW?  No Email?  No PW recovery question?

Comment: In addition to what Plutonix wrote: 1) You should only need to check if the username is already in the database. 2) You should not use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` until after you have checked if the username already exists. 3) You appear to be using `cmd` instead of `cmd2` to do the check.

Comment: can u please edit the code for me as im new in scripting ?
also yes i want it as user name and password for the starting project

Comment: Please think **very carefully** about what would happen if someone enters the following into TextBox1: `','');DROP TABLE test2;--`. This kind of thing _does happen_ all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually check to see if the username exists.

You define a query here:

```
cmd2.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, password FROM test2 WHERE username = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
```

But never execute that query.  Instead, you just execute the `INSERT` query:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

So the `INSERT` is always performed.  And since an `INSERT` doesn't return rows, you don't see the message box.

---

***First thing's first***, fix your SQL injection vulnerability.  (Personal policy, I don't like writing SQL-injectable code in an answer.)  Use query parameters instead of directly concatenating user input as code:

```
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE username = @Username"
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
If dr.HasRows Then
    MsgBox("You're already registered")
    Return
End If
```

Note a couple of things here:

- The use of a query parameter.  I had to guess on the type and size of the column in the database, adjust that as necessary.
- *Only* executing this one query.  Don't try to execute both queries at the same time, perform the first one and then perform the second one.
- You don't need, or even *want*, to include the password in this query.  You're checking if the *username* already exists, that's all.
- `Return` after showing the message, so the rest of the function doesn't execute.

*Then*, after that is done, you can perform the `INSERT` operation:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test2(Username,Password) VALUES(@Username,@Password)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This will perform the `INSERT` operation.  So if the `Return` above was never encountered then the username is unique and can be inserted.

---

***Also:*** You should *not* be storing user passwords **in plain text**.  This is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users and exposes their private data to attackers.  Instead, [obscure the password with a one-way hash](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/hasing-password-with-salt-in-visual-basic.htm) so that it *can't* be read in its original form.

---

A couple other things:

- Use meaningful variable names.  The whole reason you were having this problem was because you were getting confused between `cmd` and `cmd2`.  If your variable names carry semantic meaning, your code is a lot easier to read and understand.
- Make use of [the `Using` block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) when you have disposable resources, such as a database connection.  In general you want to open, use, and close a database connection in as small a scope as possible.  Leaving open connections hanging around is a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add unique key constraint on username and hence when it already exist it will throw duplicate entry exception.

Secondly, never save plain text password in Database, it must be hasheh and encrypted. I would suggest to better use Bcrypt of atleast level 10 to generate hashed password and also use Bcrypt dynamic salt which is mostly preferred now.

Thirdly, always use parameterized query to avoid your program from mysql injection.
For example:-

Normal:

```
 SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = 'timmy'
```

Injection:

```
 SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '' OR 1''
```